# How to create new column from the existing column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this column which is filled by string something like:

```
SX-ABC01-01-2700-W-003
```

Let's say this column name is `type_list`, and I need to create a new column called `type_list_no` which is I need the `ABC01-01` to be in the new column

How should I write my query to get the new column with the desired string in the column in SQL?

Thank you.

Comment: If this column is a "type list" then you have a broken data model.  You should not be storing multiple values in a string.  Fix the data model.  You should also explain how you define what is in the new column .  If it is fixed, then just use `'ABC01-01' as newcol`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', 3), '-', -2) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Use generated column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename
    ADD COLUMN type_list_no VARCHAR(255)
        AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(type_list, '-', 3), '-', -2));
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c9b99ad3af0a89188d16133f8f94d94)

This column will be calculated automatically from the actual value of source column. So you do not need to check that it is consistent.

This column may be indexed. In such case you may define it as VIRTUAL - it will not be stored in a table body in such case (and so it does not need in additional table space) and will be extracted from the index or recalculated from the actual source value when needed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see. Do you  see that the answers (except the expression) differs?

Comment: thankyou! I tried, but I got error says syntax error near "AS"

Comment: @yangyang Specify precise MySQL version. PS. Fiddle added.